# Adding values of car names into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I trying to make dictionary from text file, where keys will be all letter from ,, A " to ,,Z " (or 26 keys). In order to do that I wrote this lines of codes:

```
# Write file
f= open("Test.txt","w+")
f.write("Chevrolet chevelle malibu, Buick skylark 320, Plymouth satellite, amc Rebel sst, Ford torino,  Ford galaxie 500, Chevrolet Impala, Plymouth fury III,     
  Pontiac catalina, amc Ambassador dpl, Dodge Challenger se, Plymouth 'cuda 340, Chevrolet Monte Carlo")


# Open the file in read mode 
text = open("Test.txt", "r") 


import string
list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:10])

# Making keys
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase[:13]

d_alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase[0:26] ) 
print(d_alphabet)
```

So next step should be to add value of each key. Each value should be a list with the car names starting with the respective letter (e.g If a car name starts with a small letter instead of a capital one, also include it in the dictionary under the capital letter A).

So can anybody help me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import string

car_dict = {k: [] for k in string.ascii_lowercase[0:26]}
with open('Test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for car in map(str.strip, line.split(',')):
            car_dict[car[0].lower()].append(car)
```

Here the result:

```sh
{'a': ['amc Rebel sst', 'amc Ambassador dpl'], 'b': ['Buick skylark 320'], 'c': ['Chevrolet chevelle malibu', 'Chevrolet Impala', 'Chevrolet Monte Carlo'], 'd': ['Dodge Challenger se'], 'e': [], 'f': ['Ford torino', 'Ford galaxie 500'], 'g': [], 'h': [], 'i': [], 'j': [], 'k': [], 'l': [], 'm': [], 'n': [], 'o': [], 'p': ['Plymouth satellite', 'Plymouth fury III', 'Pontiac catalina', "Plymouth 'cuda 340"], 'q': [], 'r': [], 's': [], 't': [], 'u': [], 'v': [], 'w': [], 'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}
```

If you want a dictionary with only letters with a least one associated car:

```py
car_dict = {}
with open('Test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for car in map(str.strip, line.split(',')):
            car_dict.setdefault(car[0].lower(), []).append(car)
```

```sh
{'c': ['Chevrolet chevelle malibu', 'Chevrolet Impala', 'Chevrolet Monte Carlo'], 'b': ['Buick skylark 320'], 'p': ['Plymouth satellite', 'Plymouth fury III', 'Pontiac catalina', "Plymouth 'cuda 340"], 'a': ['amc Rebel sst', 'amc Ambassador dpl'], 'f': ['Ford torino', 'Ford galaxie 500'], 'd': ['Dodge Challenger se']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` to directly update as you go along:

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = open("Test.txt", "r") 

res = defaultdict(list)
for line in text: # iterate over lines if there are multiple lines in the files
    cars = line.split(',')
    for car in cars:
        car = car.strip()
        letter = car[0].lower()
        res[letter].append(car)

text.close()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'c': ['Chevrolet chevelle malibu', 'Chevrolet Impala', 'Chevrolet Monte Carlo'], 'b': ['Buick skylark 320'], 'p': ['Plymouth satellite', 'Plymouth fury III', 'Pontiac catalina', "Plymouth 'cuda 340"], 'a': ['amc Rebel sst', 'amc Ambassador dpl'], 'f': ['Ford torino', 'Ford galaxie 500'], 'd': ['Dodge Challenger se']})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted your code so it works and used uppercase letters:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase


f= open("Test.txt","w+")
f.write("Chevrolet chevelle malibu, Buick skylark 320, Plymouth satellite, amc Rebel sst, Ford torino,  Ford galaxie 500, Chevrolet Impala, Plymouth fury III,"
  "Pontiac catalina, amc Ambassador dpl, Dodge Challenger se, Plymouth 'cuda 340, Chevrolet Monte Carlo")
f.close()  # close it so you can open it again


text = open("Test.txt", "r")
cars = [(car[0].upper(), car) for car in text.read().split(", ")]  # List of tuples with car letter and car name
car_list = []
car_dict = {}
for char in ascii_uppercase:
    for i, car in cars:
        if i == char:
            car_list.append(car)
    if car_list:  # adds cars to dictionary if cars with that first letter exist
        car_dict[char] = car_list
        car_list = []  # clear car list to start again
print(car_dict)
```